# Assembly program never stops (Turbo Debugger)

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I am trying to read a number and print it on screen in assembly language using TASM.
Until now I have a macro to read and a macro to print:

```
.386
DATA SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'DATA'
X DD 0  ;number to be read
AU DD 0   ;auxiliary variable
DATA ENDS

READ MACRO X, AUX  ;macro to read
LOCAL R, FINAL
PUSH EAX  ;save the registers we will work with
PUSH EBX
PUSH EDX

MOV EBX, 10
R:
   MOV AH, 1H
   INT 21H   ;read character
   CMP AL, 0DH  ;compare to 'Enter' key
   JE FINAL
   CMP AL,30H  ;see if it's a number above 0
   JB R
   CMP AL, 39H  ;see if it's a number below 9
   JA R
   SUB AL, 48  ;transform character to number
   XOR AH,AH
   MOV AUX,EAX 
   MOV EAX, X
   MUL EBX     ;construct the number
   ADD EAX, AUX
   MOV X, EAX
   JMP R

FINAL:
POP EDX
POP EBX
ENDM

PRINT MACRO NUMBER
LOCAL LOOPR, PRINTLN
PUSH EAX   ;save registers we will work with
PUSH EDX
PUSH EBX
PUSH SI
MOV CX, 0
MOV EAX, NUMBER
MOV EBX, 10
LOOPR:
  XOR EDX, EDX
  DIV EBX    ; eax <- eax/10, edx <- eax % 10
  ADD DL, '0'  ; edx to ASCII
  PUSH DX    
  INC CX
  CMP EAX, 0
  JNZ LOOPR
PRINTLN:
  POP DX
  MOV AH, 2H
  INT 21H
  DEC CX
  JNZ PRINTLN

  MOV DL, 13D  ;carriage return
  MOV AH, 2H
  INT 21H
  MOV DL, 10D  ;line feed
  MOV AH, 2H
  INT 21H

  POP SI
  POP EDX
  POP EAX
ENDM 


CODE SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'
START PROC FAR
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA
PUSH DS
XOR AX,AX
PUSH AX
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX

READ X, AU
PRINT X

RET
START ENDP
CODE ENDS
END START
```

If I run the code in Turbo Debugger it reads the number, but the program keeps running and running and I don't know why.
[image: Turbo Debugger window]
 My personal guess is that this has to do with the `.386` directive. I've had a similar problem with another program and after I removed the `.386` directive it worked. But here I need the directive since I use 32 bit registers. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I haven't looked at the code thoroughly, but I think you haven't popped EAX.

Comment: I tried to pop EAX as well, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does matter where the `.386` is. Move it to a line behind the `CODE SEGMENT ...` line:

```
...
CODE SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'
.386

START PROC FAR
...
```

`READ` needs a `POP EAX` at the end:

```
...
FINAL:
POP EDX
POP EBX
POP EAX
ENDM
...
```

`PRINT` needs a `POP EBX` at the end:

```
...
  POP SI
  POP EBX
  POP EDX
  POP EAX
ENDM
...
```

`READ` performs just a Carriage Return (0x0D = 13d) at the end. So, `PRINT` will write on the same row, overwrite the input and you will see no change. Add a Line Feed (0x0A = 10d) to `READ`:

```
...
FINAL:
mov dl, 10
mov ah, 2
int 21h

POP EDX
POP EBX
pop eax
ENDM
...
```